# Is there a polar liquid with a high electrolysis potential?

Tags: electrolysis

I'm trying to use $\ce{Na2SO4}$ for intercalation of sulfate ions in van der Waals stacked materials (as anodes). With water as the solvent, there is some indication of hydroxyl radical forming due to the applied potential being larger than the standard potential of water electrolysis (1.23 V).

I am aware that hydroxyl scavengers such as ascorbic acid can be used to, well, scavenge hydroxyls. Yet I'm wondering if there is a solvent for $\ce{Na2SO4}$ that would only decompose at a higher potential difference.

Comment: Either you won't have electrolysis at all, or you will have products of electrolysis, there is no third option. What kind of products would you want?

Comment: Thanks for your input Ivan. I've changed the details of the question to more accurately describe what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: So I guess you don't care much about sodium? Maybe you should change it to tetraethylammonium? That would make the salt better soluble in various organics.

Comment: I will definetly look into using lipophilic salts, thank you!